# How to determine given file is a class file?

Tags: c#, java

I need to determine that whether a given file is a class file or not. Suppose I change the extension to .exe/.xml or some other, I need to determine whether that given file, if a class file will be parsed differently and if it would be some other, it'll be parsed in that manner.

How can I read the class file format?

Comment: -1 - For asking a question about reading Java class files, tagging the question with just "java" ... and expecting everyone to know that you want a solution coded in C# / .NET.

Comment: @Stephen C, I would downvote your comment ( if I could ) , for complaining about something and don't fix it when you have enough powers. I guess I have to wait for votes to be downvoted ; )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) lets you do this. Checking now...

EDIT: Yes, it does. You can use the [ClassParser](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassParser.html) class; the `parse` method will throw a `ClassFormatException` if the file isn't really a Java class file.

EDIT: Okay, so you need to know from C#. Three options:

- Check whether the header is 0xcafebabe and leave it at that (it'll be a pretty good heuristic)
- Port BCEL to C# (just the bits you need, obviously)
- Try using J# to compile BCEL to .NET directly - that will only work if it doesn't use anything beyond Java 1.1.4, but you *may* find a really old version of BCEL works fine in that respect. Of course you'll need to get hold of J# as well, which is now discontinued.

The CAFEBABE test is very easy:

```
public bool IsProbablyJava(string file)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        return stream.ReadByte() == 0xca &&
               stream.ReadByte() == 0xfe &&
               stream.ReadByte() == 0xba &&
               stream.ReadByte() == 0xbe;
    }
}
```

It's not exactly pretty... there are alternatives with `BinaryReader` etc as well.

Comment: I need that to determine in C# .NET not in Java

Comment: But you tagged your question as "java". So are you coding a C# app to read Java code or are you coding a C# app to read C# code?

Comment: yeah probably because of Java related question. But as framework(currently on which I am working) written in .NET env to process files. I think you've got my point.

Comment: @Usman: And how were we supposed to know that? *Please* be more considerate when writing questions in future.

Comment: Thnaks Jon for your great help.
It works for cases which i just tested. Hope will work for rest offs as well.

Answer (score 9):

Java .class files start with HEX: `0xCAFE 0xBABE` That's a good start:

[CAFE BABE http://a.imageshack.us/img820/2908/capturadepantalla201007k.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img820/2908/capturadepantalla201007k.png)

Comment: Thanks but what tool you used of which you pasted screen short? If its debugger or dissassembler sort of , do let me know about this

Comment: @Usman, that particular screenshot is gVim but, as aioobe says, any "decent" text editor must have it.

Answer (score 2):

The [class file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28file_format%29) says that the first four bytes of a class file will be `CA FE BA BE`, so you could check for that. Depending on your requirements, that might be a simple enough check.

As an alternative (and possibly better) solution, just try to load the file. If it fails, then it wasn't a class file. If it succeeds, then it was.

Comment: Be careful with the alternative.  It is a straight-forward idea.  However the class could have static initializers with unintended side effects.